# how to send array of table checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am new to development and I had the following issue.

[image: checkbox Table]

From above image as you can see I have a ***pagename*** and three Radio buttons ***view***, ***edit*** and ***update***.
Below is my code:

```
<td>{{product name}} </td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox"  :value="{id:props.row.id,value:'true',seq:'view'}"  v-model="checkview" >
</td>

<td>
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkedit" :value="{id:props.row.id,value:'true' ,seq:'edit'}" >
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox"  v-model="checkupdate" :value="{id:props.row.id,value:'true',seq:'update'}">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox"  v-model="checkdelete" :value="{id:props.row.id,value:'true',seq:'delete'}">
</td>
```

#### Now my problem is that how can I store these *checkboxes* values into database.

> What will be the Structure of `Schema` for this condition.

For Example Let

- product id is 1

If a User Check all three radio buttons.Then data stored in the `database` would be like this

```
     Product. | View  | edit.  | update
        1.      | True. | True  | true
```

Comment: Your trying to make this to complex.  Checkbox inputs are Boolean values so just do unique check box values for each option and post the values.

Comment: @technology thank for you suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you can send multiple values for a single field using HTML forms, by using the [] syntax.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="apple">apple
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="pear">pear
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="fig">fig
```

when this form is posted, you'll receive an array (or list) of values for the field 'fruit' which you can manipulate on the server before storing a database.

or, you can use individual checkboxes with unique names, i.e.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="like_apple" value="ticked">apple
<input type="checkbox" name="like_pear" value="ticked">pear
<input type="checkbox" name="like_fig" value="ticked">fig
```

it depends on how you best want to structure the data for use later.

there's a good guide here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

however, it looks like you might be using a template language here which is automatically parsing your HTML to populate it with variables, so there maybe some existing logic which is already handling these forms, which you should look at the documentation for.

Answer (score 0):

> #### Use *PHP* `Serialize()` and `Unserialize()` Functions

```
<!-- language: html -->
<input type="checkbox" name="radioButton" value="view">
<input type="checkbox" name="radioButton" value="edit">
<input type="checkbox" name="radioButton" value="update">
```

Assume your all `radio` buttons checked. Then in your `store()` method
`$data->serialize($request->radioButton);`

#### Data will be stored in serialized format

> Assume your table structure like this

```
PageId |        Permission  
1      | a:3:{i:0;s:4:"view";i:1;s:4:"edit";i:2;s:6:"update";}
```

> When need to use this use `Unserialize()`

```
$data->unserialize($dataFromDB);
```

Result will be an array:-

```
array (
  0 => 'view',
  1 => 'edit',
  2 => 'update',
)
```